# Why is my CUPS printer stalling and failing for print jobs larger than 4 kilobytes?"

Tags: rhel, cups, syslog

So, we have several Redhat Enterprise Linux servers for an internal application that we support in our team at the office. Among other things, the servers send "auto-print" reports of various activities to a logging system via a CUPS printer nicknamed "syslog".

All was well until recently, where we did an application flip from one server to another, and since then, we noticed that the logging system has been receiving much less data than before for that environment. Instead of all print jobs being pretty much instantly processed like before, several of them now take a while to complete (often more than 10min despite the job files being no more than a few dozen kilobytes), and don't even show up on the logging system's webpage once "completed" on our server's side. After a bit of experimentation, I noticed that print jobs of 4096 bytes or lower still go through without issue, but anything bigger than that will most likely stall and never make it to the destination. Here's an example screenshot if it can help clarify what I'm talking about :

[image: syslog example comparison]

This has been quite puzzling to troubleshoot, since the configurations of the syslog printer appear to be the same on both the current and previous server (and said previous server can process larger print jobs pretty much instantly, and they're then visible on the logging system too). I thought it was an issue with a hardcoded limit of kilobytes per job somehow, so we re-created the printer through the lpadmin command with option -o job-k-limit=0 , but that didn't seem to help. Someone from the Linux SysAdmin team also found a cups setting called "LimitRequestBody" and set it to 0, but that didn't seem to help either.

We're quite frankly out of ideas as to what may be the cause of this. We'll have someone from Telecom on Tuesday to investigate for any potential networking issues between that server and the logging system, but in the meantime, if any of you has any idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it was an issue with the Palo Alto Firewall. A rule was added and now things are going through smoothly. Good stuff !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).